# What do you get if you glue a disk twice around a circle?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I would like to know what you get if you glue the disk $D^2$ around the circle $S^1$ via the map $\phi \colon \partial D^2\to S^1$, $\phi (e^{i\theta})=e^{2i\theta}$. I would have thought you would get a Moebius band, my reasoning being that $\mathbb{RP}^2$ is obtained by glueing a disk to a disk via this map, and that $\mathbb{RP}^2$ is also what is obtained by gluing a disk along the boundary of a Moebius band. 
The reason I think my reasoning must be wrong is that I am reading Hatcher, in which he states the following

(*) if you have a 1-complex $X$ and attach a 2-cell via a map $\phi$ to obtain a 2-complex, then the loop in $Y$ given by $t\mapsto \phi(t)$ will be null-homotopic.

Since the loop in the Moebius band which follows its boundary is not null homotopic, my reasoning gives a contradiction. I am hoping that once this example becomes clear, the statement (*) will become clear.

Many Thanks, A.

Comment: You actually get $\mathbb{RP}^2$ if you do this.

Comment: Interesting! Do you have any nice ways to visualise this? It seems counter-intuitive to me that you can glue a disk around a circle and obtain something without boundary. I would have though you would end up with something with a circle for its boundary!

Comment: oh wait i have understood it now. because the two halfs of the disk each take a full copy of the circle in the boundary, and they share this circle, the resulting object is closed... thanks very much!

Comment: yup yup yup.. all making more sense now :)